# Create object when created another object in Django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to create object when I created another object in Django?

I have code like this and I would like to create AnotherModel instance firstly and then Model instance (when creating AnotherModel).

```py
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharFiled(max_length=50)

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
```

I tried use Django signals - pre_save.

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=AnotherModel)
def save_model(sender, **kwargs):
    # some code
```

But I have exception like this:

ValueError: Cannot assign "u'Test": "AnotherModel.resource" must be a "Model" instance.

Comment: It looks like you did the `# some code` the wrong way, since you have set the `name` of your `Model` to the `model` (well `resource`) of your `AnotherModel` instead of its primary key. But that being said, Signals are usually not a good idea: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/ A lot of ORM calls like `.update(..)`, `.bulk_create`, etc. can circumvent these.

Comment: @swozny13, can you provide the line of code when you are creating the instance of `AnotherModel`?

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to **create object** when I **created another object** in Django?

Yes, you can, do you have two options:

1) **Option 1**: Overriding save ( [Overriding predefined model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) )

```
from django.db import models

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:  # create
            self.model = Model.objects.create( name = "some random name" )
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

2) **Option 2**: [Using pre-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver    

@receiver(pre_save, sender=AnotherModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender.pk is None:  # create
        sender.model = Model.objects.create( name = "some random name" )
```

**Important**:

The related model must be created before to save current one. In examples I used:

```
Model.objects.create( name = "some random name" )
```

But you can create model as a regular way:

```
m = Model()
m.name = "random name"
m.save()  # <--- important!
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create an object when another one is created. I think using a signal is possibly the best way to do it.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver    

@receiver(pre_save, sender=AnotherModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender.pk is None:
        sender.model = Model.objects.create(name="Name")
```

you just have to create an instance of `AnotherModel` so that the implemented signal is raised:

```
>>> o = AnotherModel.objects.create(description='This is a silly description')
```

You can check that an instance of `Model` has been created and assigned to `o.model`:

```
>>> o.model
```