# How to create a child at the time of creating a parent - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two models and I don't know how to create an 'ExDocument' child associated with its field extension when creating the parent 'Document'.

**Document:**

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    documentId = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2555)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="Doc_Own", blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="Doc_Aut", blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super().save(**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**ExDocument:**

```
class ExDocument(models.Model):
    doc_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    ex_name = models.OneToOneField(Document, related_name='ExDoc', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ex_name.name

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.ex_name:
            self.ex_name.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56991195/create-object-when-created-another-object-in-django). Also, I suggest you set `related_name` using snake case like `ex_document`.